# OpenAL on iPhone suddenly becomes really quiet

Tags: iphone, ios, volume, openal

As the title states, sounds will just play at ridiculously quiet volumes. I thought it wasn't playing at all until I heard sounds barely audible at max volume.

It's been fine for weeks. Not a problem. Suddenly it started doing this out of nowhere. I've tried cleaning/rebuilding, restarting Xcode, restarting device, etc. Nothing fixes it. It'll just suddenly come back again in a random build. This is really starting to frustrate me and I'm disappointed I went with OpenAL, as this isn't the first problem I've had with it in just a few weeks of using it. I can't release anything with sound that MIGHT work sometimes.

I'm using AVAudioPlayer simultaneously to play background music, and have not had a single problem with that.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

In response to  user1260708:

My init method looks like this

```
bool D2DSoundController::init(Map<D2DSound> *sounds) {
if (!_initialzed) {
    OSStatus result = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, &_interruptionListener, (void*)_context);
    ulong cat = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    result |= AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(cat), &cat);
    _sounds = sounds;
    _device = alcOpenDevice(0);
    if (_device != 0) {
        _context = alcCreateContext(_device, 0);
        if (_context != 0) {
            alcMakeContextCurrent(_context);
            alGenSources(_numSources, _sources);
            //alDistanceModel(AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE_CLAMPED);
            //alListener3f(AL_POSITION, 300.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f); --- I think this was the problem?
            _initialzed = true;

            return (alGetError() == 0 && result == 0);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
return false;
```

}

However, I think I found the issue. After commenting out the alListener3f call (just noticed it as the line above had been commented out for a while), it seems to be working again. I don't see why this suddenly became an issue though, as it's been there the whole time; distance attentuation wasn't working right for me either (reason that call was there in the first place, for testing), so I decided overall not to use it, but I guess I forgot to remove that line.
See this question: [Distance Attenuation with OpenAL on iPhone/iPod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594830/distance-attentuation-with-openal-on-iphone-ipod)

Any input on the attentuation issue (which seems to be the root of this as well) would be great though!

As I side note, since I dropped attentuation, I've been using stereo as well, which shouldn't be affecting that, so I'm still confused.

Comment: can you provide us with some code please?

Comment: Posted it. Upon review, I think I found the cause, but still unsure of the reason.